# use nested list in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a 1d queryset and I want it to be nested based on its each value. For example, in a template like below

```
<ul>
  {% for dept in dept_queryset %}
      <li>{{ dept.code }} {{ dept.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I see something like this

```
1000 a
1100 b
1200 c
2000 q
2100 w
2110 e
2111 t
...
2200 t
2210 h
2211 b
...
2300 p
```

What I want is however something like this:

```
1000 a
    1100 b
    1200 c
2000 q
    2100 w
        2110 e
            2111 t
...
    2200 t
        2210 h
            2211 b
...
    2300 p
```

I can hard code each queryset and use it in as context, but I'd like to know if there is any pythonic way. I tried `divisible by` filter, with no success. And I'm aware that I should change my template tag of course, I hope to get some guidance about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show what you tried `'I tried divisible by filter, with no success'`.

Comment: for a starter I tried something like this: `{% if dept.code|divisibleby: "1000" %}`, which didn't work. I'm not sure how I can apply that logic, since `divisibleby` only returns boolean, and it can only be used with template variables, not with tags in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template filter [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) should work for you. It seems that your error is adding a space between filter and the second argument; there should be no space.

So this should work:

```
<ul>
  {% for dept in dept_queryset %}
      <li>
          {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"10" %}&nbsp;{% endif %}
          {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"100" %}&nbsp;{% endif %}
          {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"1000" %}&nbsp;{% endif %}
          {{ dept.code }} {{ dept.name }}
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

You commented that you would like nested HTML lists. That is rather tricky and complicated to do in the template with just the template filters. That kind of nested grouping would be better done in the view with Python code

The closest that I can do in just the template would be a HTML table with different number of empty cells before the data, maybe like this:

```
<table>
{% for dept in dept_queryset %}
    <tr>
        {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"10" %}<td></td>{% endif %}
        {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"100" %}<td></td>{% endif %}
        {% if not dept.code|divisibleby:"1000" %}<td></td>{% endif %}
        <td>{{ dept.code }} {{ dept.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could I however make the `li` more semantically? I mean I want something like using nested ul tag for items `divisibleby:"100"` under 1000 or something.